# Align multiple labels to left of form input

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to stack two `<span>` tags in a form input label. At the moment, they're sitting next to each other, but I'm not sure how to move `span.label-sm` under the regular span. I've already set it to `display: block;`.

Desired outcome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKQDC.jpg.

HTML:

```
<div id="appraisals-form" class="contact-form">
    <form role="form" method="post" action="contact-form.php">
        <label for="name"><span>Name</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your name." /></label>
        <label for="email"><span>Email</span><input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your email address." /></label>
        <label for="email"><span>Phone</span><input type="tel" class="input-field" name="phone" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your phone number." /></label>

        <label for="name"><span>Type of Artwork</span><span class="label-sm">(i.e. sculpture, painting...)</span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your item's type of artwork." /></label>

        <label for="message"><span>Message</span><textarea name="message" class="textarea-field" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your message."></textarea></label>
        <div class="centred-button"><input type="submit" value="" class="submit-button" /></div>                  
    </form>             
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact-form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 600px;
    font-family: 'LinotypeUniversW01-Thin_723604', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.contact-form label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase; /* New */
}

.contact-form label > span {
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.contact-form label > span, #recaptcha::before {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    content: "";
}

.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
}

.contact-form input.input-field {
    width: 70%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.contact-form .textarea-field {
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}

.contact-form .textarea-field, .g-recaptcha {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.g-recaptcha {
    height: 78px !important;
}

#recaptcha {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 24px 0px;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

input.submit-button {
    background-image: url("../img/submit-button.jpg");
    width: 225px;
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
}






.appraisals .section-title {
    width: 100%;
}

#appraisals-form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    top: auto;
    transform: none;
}

#appraisals-form label > span {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 16px
}

#appraisals-form span.label-sm {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: none;
}

#appraisals-form input, #appraisals-form textarea {
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

#appraisals-form textarea {
    height: 100px;
}

#appraisals-form .centred-button {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tcap2Lcp/.

Any help would really appreciated!

Comment: sorry i don't get what you want...

Comment: For span.label-sm to sit under span, like this: http://i.imgur.com/fXkvNTu.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this task with CSS positioning properties.

[image]

HTML

```
<!-- ADJUSTED BLOCK START -->
<label for="name" style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
   <span style="width: 24%; padding: 0; position: relative; left: -2%;">
       Type of Artwork</span>
   <span style="width: 24%; padding: 0; position: absolute; left: -2%; bottom: 30%;"
      class="label-sm">(i.e. sculpture, painting...)</span>
   <input style="width: 70%" type="text" name="name"
      required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your item's type of artwork.">
</label>
<!-- ADJUSTED BLOCK END-->
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/tcap2Lcp/4/)

I used inline styles for brevity and clarity. Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I'll have to work on cleaning up the CSS too.

Comment: Though it works, there are lots of static values, which I typically consider kinda "hack-y". Do you think it's the best method in this case? Thanks again.

Comment: Percentage values work nicely, if you want to switch to that. Whether you use fixed or relative values, you'll probably want a media query when the screen width breaks below 700px. That's when the labels begin to wrap.

Comment: That could work. As we all do, I just try to accomplish anything in the least amount of code possible. Also keeping responsiveness in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Like I mentioned, your form layout starts to break when the screen resizes below 700px width. But this isn't unique to this form element and my answer doesn't cause any unique breaks. This form element goes when the entire form goes.

Comment: Yeah, that's expected. I'll write specific styles in a media query later. I'll test this out!

Comment: Sounds good. Also, if you're not sold on this method let me know. I've used CSS positioning properties because it's simple, stable and effective. But the task can also be achieved with HTML tables, CSS table properties, and (possibly) CSS Flexbox.

Comment: I'm not completely, mostly because I expected a more re-usable method, I guess, but I really appreciate your help. I thought it would've just taken a few floats, displays, and text-aligns instead of manual positionings. I don't think I want to use HTML tables, but if you're wiling to try something else, please go ahead!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87331/discussion-between-michael-b-and-mario-parra).

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to my first answer, which uses CSS positioning properties and width adjustments to align the labels on the left of the input, this solution keeps things **very simple** with only HTML.

The idea is to display the small labels as **[placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)** text.

This element gets deleted:

```
<span class="label-sm">(i.e. sculpture, painting...)</span>
```

But the text goes into a placeholder:

```
<label for="name">
    <span>Type of Artwork</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" required 
    data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your item's type of artwork."
    placeholder="(i.e. sculpture, painting...)" >
</label>
```

And that's it!

[image]

Clean, simple, reusable code (as you requested). Easy to maintain. User-friendly. And no changes to the CSS... 
*unless you decide you want to [style the placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)*.

Answer (score 2):

This will nest the two `<span>` tags without changing the appearnce:

```
<span>Type of Artwork</span><span class="label-sm">(i.e. sculpture, painting...)</span></span>
```

I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve though, so not sure if your CSS needs a small change, possibly:

```
.label-sm {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right this should work for you - just add `float: none;` to `#appraisals-form span.label-sm`.

Here is the whole css:

```
.contact-form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 600px;
    font-family: 'LinotypeUniversW01-Thin_723604', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.contact-form label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase; /* New */
}

.contact-form label > span {
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.contact-form label > span, #recaptcha::before {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    content: "";
}

.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
}

.contact-form input.input-field {
    width: 70%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.contact-form .textarea-field {
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}

.contact-form .textarea-field, .g-recaptcha {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.g-recaptcha {
    height: 78px !important;
}

#recaptcha {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 24px 0px;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

input.submit-button {
    background-image: url("../img/submit-button.jpg");
    width: 225px;
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
}

.appraisals .section-title {
    width: 100%;
}

#appraisals-form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    top: auto;
    transform: none;
}

#appraisals-form label > span {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 16px
}

#appraisals-form span.label-sm {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: none;
    float: none;
}

#appraisals-form input, #appraisals-form textarea {
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

#appraisals-form textarea {
    height: 100px;
}

#appraisals-form .centred-button {
    text-align: center;
}
```

hope it helps :)

## Further explanation

The problem was caused by `float: left;` at `.contact-form label > span` which floatet your span in general.

Comment: That got the spans on two lines, but now the input field is left-aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/tcap2Lcp/1/.

Comment: best practice would be to show up a picture that shows the whole form how you want it to look like...

Comment: Well, I haven't finished building the whole form yet, but this is the intended layout: http://i.imgur.com/CkOKeWl.jpg.

Comment: If necessary, yes, sure.

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way is to add this class to CSS :

```
label {float: left; width: 10em; margin-right: 1em; text-align: right;}
```

Comment: it's not a good idea to target ALL the labels, better scope it to `.contact-form > form > label`